# Replace balanced brackets with balanced braces in LaTeX

Tags: latex, replace, tex

How can I write a (La)TeX command that replaces all [ with { and all ] with }, assuming that every [ has a matching ], and that any braces between the [ and ] are balanced?  It needs to be able to deal with nested brackets.

For example, I want to be able to write a command `\mynewcommand` so that `\mynewcommand{{[[{1}{2}][{3}{4}]]}}` is the same as `\mycommand{{{{{1}{2}}{{3}{4}}}}}`.

Comment: Do you want it to replace the brackets with curlies as *grouping* characters or as characters which will be typeset?

Comment: I want it to replace them with braces that are valid for grouping and argument-passing (i.e., it's not sufficient to have them act like \bgroup and \egroup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use e-TeX and \scantokens

```
\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \everyeof{\noexpand}%
    \endlinechar=-1\relax
    \catcode`\[=1\relax
    \catcode`\]=2\relax
    \edef\temp{\scantokens{#1}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp}%
}
```

This will define \temp with the material in #1 but with every "[" ... "]" pair turned into a TeX brace group ("{" ... "}"). You can then use \temp to do whatever you want. As I say, this requires e-TeX, which is available in all modern TeX systems.